# Whenever i connect to Mosquitto MQTT under subscribe function getting granted as empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

Below is my code

```
mqtt_client.on('connect', (data) => {
        logger.info('Connack Packet', data);
            mqtt_client.subscribe([
                env.topic.status,
                env.topic.error,], { qos: 1 }, (err, grant) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Failed to subscribe to a topic', err);
                        process.exit(1);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Subscribed Topics', grant);
                        let subscribedTopics = "";
                        for (let g of grant) {
                            subscribedTopics += g.topic + "\n";
                        }
                        console.info(`Waiting for messages on ${subscribedTopics}`);
                    }
                });
    });
```

so when i disconnect mosquitto and if i reconnect i am getting grant array as empty

and also why it is connecting to old session only instead of connecting to new

below is my config

```
const options = { 
host: mqttConfigPointer.host, 
port: mqttConfigPointer.port, 
protocol: mqttConfigPointer.protocol, 
clean: false, 
clientId: CLIENTID, 
protocolId: MQTT, 
protocolVersion: 5, 
connectTimeout: 30000, 
keepalive: 60, 
rejectUnauthorized: false 
};
```

I am running mosquitto in one docker and my app in other docker

so when i remove mosquitto docker and re-deploy then app will connect but cant able to receive any messages so i have to restart app docker also then it will work why is this so happening

Though it is persistance client once i remove docker all its db files are removed so still where it is storing and session is maintaining

i had also put check on if session is present or not if there then i am not subscribing so

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65640239/edit) the question to include the code use to connect, specifically how you are setting the `cleanSession` flag and clientId

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `cleanSession` set to `false` you have created a persistent session. This means that the broker will remember that the client (based on the `clientID`) is already still subscribed to those topics when you reconnect.

Hence the request to subscribe is returning and empty grant list because the client is already subscribed to those topics.

Please look at this article for more details: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/